# Blutooth Audio Problems on Mac Book Pro

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth, macbook-pro, speakers

Music audio plays fine from Mac Book Pro to a Vizio 54" sound bar but spoken audio breaks up...any clues? 
I've tried moving my computer closer. 
This only happens when playing back movies either from a DVD or from Mpeg file.

Answer (score 0):

Some surround sound systems will try to synthesize a center channel from a stereo (only left and right, no center) audio input. Basically, any audio that's the same in both the left and right streams is considered to be center, and put on the center channel. Dialog in movies is usually the same in both channels of the stereo mix, so dialog usually ends up on the center channel. This is why boosting the center channel is often used when you want to hear the dialog better.

The sound bar could be having trouble synthesizing the center channel from a stereo Bluetooth A2DP stream. If you use the analog headphone jack to send the same audio to the sound bar, does it have the same problem? If so, then the problem is probably with your sound bar's attempt to synthesize a center channel, not a problem with your Mac's Bluetooth.